# How to restrict when click on anchor tag it should not redirect to another page

Tags: html

Here I have simple anchor tag. When I click on it, it is redirecting to another page. How can I restrict it from doing this?

`<td><a href="#">Select</a></td>`

When I click on Select it is opened as `http://localhost:14239/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `href` attribute. Or, with javascript `onclick="return false;"`